# Cannot hit second endpoint in Microsoft Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, rest, azure-cognitive-search

I have a simple application that uses Microsoft Azure Cognitive Search to crawl 2 tables, a `post` table and a `comment` table. I have the two indexes set up exactly the same way, and I'm attempting to retrieve the results the same way. The `post` search works without issue, but the `comment` post errors each time on the `OPTIONS` http request with an error message that reads:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"https://[search-uri].search.windows.net/indexes/comment-view-index/docs?api-version=2020-06-30","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://[search-uri].search.windows.net/indexes/comment-view-index/docs?api-version=2020-06-30: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}

Here are how the URIs are constructed:

```
public static searchUri = `https://${ServerDetails.searchServiceName}.search.windows.net/indexes/${ServerDetails.searchIndexName}/docs?api-version=${ServerDetails.apiVersion}`;
public static searchUriComment = `https://${ServerDetails.searchServiceName}.search.windows.net/indexes/${ServerDetails.searchIndexNameComment}/docs?api-version=${ServerDetails.apiVersion}`;
```

Here are the service calls:

```
searchData(query: string): Observable<any> {
        let result: Observable<any> = null;
        const options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'api-key': ServerDetails.searchServiceAdminApiKey,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        };
        result = this.http.post(ServerDetails.searchUri, JSON.stringify({
            search: query
        }), options);
        return result;
    }

    searchDataComments(query: string): Observable<any> {
        let result: Observable<any> = null;
        const options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'api-key': ServerDetails.searchServiceAdminApiKey,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            })
        };
        result = this.http.post(ServerDetails.searchUriComment, JSON.stringify({
            search: query
        }), options);
        return result;
    }
```

And this is being called here:

```
getSearchData(): Promise<any[]>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.serv.searchDataComments(this.searchTerm).subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data.value;
                this.dataOnChanged.next(this.data);
                resolve(this.data);
            }, reject);
        });
    }
```

I can hit both of the uris via `GET` and `POST` requests in Postman, but all attempts at an `OPTIONS` call in Postman fail.
`CORS` is allowed for all origins on both indexes.

Comment: Can you pls confirm on the CORS policy. Because the status 0 usually indicates the CORS issue

Comment: @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT, I have allowed CORS from all origins

Comment: The URLs only look valid for the GET Search API, not the POST Search API. I'm surprised that one index worked but the other didn't. Try adding /search to the end of the URL and see if that helps.